# something wrong with my keras's embedding's test

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

Here is my python's code runned on pyspark with distkeras.

```
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import *
from distkeras.trainers import *
from pyspark import SQLContext


sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
reader = sqlContext
raw_dataset = reader.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferSchema='true').load(
    '/home/hpcc/test/11.csv')
# raw_dataset = raw_dataset.repartition(4)
features = raw_dataset.columns
features.remove('C0')
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=features, outputCol="features")
dataset = vector_assembler.transform(raw_dataset)
dataset = dataset.select("features", "C0")
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(input_dim=52965, output_dim=256))
model1.add(LSTM(128))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
model1.add(Dense(1))
model1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model1.summary()
optimizer_mlp= 'adagrad'
loss_mlp = 'binary_crossentropy'
dataset.cache()
trainer = DOWNPOUR(keras_model=model1, worker_optimizer=optimizer_mlp, loss=loss_mlp, num_workers=4,
                   batch_size=16, communication_window=5, learning_rate=0.1, num_epoch=1,
                   features_col="features", label_col="C0")
trainer.set_parallelism_factor(1)
trained_model = trainer.train(dataset)
```

But it print error like this:

```
16/12/30 20:53:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/distkeras/workers.py", line 193, in train
    X = np.asarray([x[self.features_column] for x in feature_iterator])
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 769, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError("Index %d out of bounds." % index)
ValueError: Index 50 out of bounds.
```

My 11.csv is like this :

```
1,23,5211,871,1223,11,5,355,9999,1,28032,33057,1259,5575,4,1,9604,23790,83,136,18,4695,3,121,1,151,521,2,130,24677,4,1,612,947,612,1645,4534,59,29008,1,21679,1,416,3474,3,4189,1,142,5,11323,3
........
```

It's C0 column is label,and C1 to C50 are features.
Hope for your answer.Thanks a lots.

Here is dataset.printSchema():

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- C0: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: >>> dataset.printSchema()

root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- C0: integer (nullable = true)

Comment: >>> dataset.show()

+--------------------+---+
|            features| C0|
+--------------------+---+
|[23.0,5211.0,871....|  1|
|[138.0,10992.0,4....|  1|
|[906.0,182.0,13.0...|  1|
|[1307.0,29.0,11.0...|  1|
|[836.0,1.0,46.0,2...|  1|
|[216.0,22425.0,43...|  1|
|[1208.0,1.0,146.0...|  1|
|[2.0,794.0,7053.0...|  1|
|[930.0,307.0,2681...|  1|
|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|  1|
|[21.0,129.0,5090....|  1|
|[908.0,4.0,120.0,...|  1|
|[321.0,944.0,1733...|  1|
+--------------------+---+